# How to create a Grid in R for Kriging

Tags: r, vector-grid, kriging, soilgrids

I have done my work for creating variograms etc, and i would like to run kriging. I've loaded my dataset, and i know that i should create a grid file, but i don't know how.

I have the shapefile from my area. What i should do next to create the grid? I want to execute kriging in the area that i have the shapefile.

```
setwd("D:/R/WorkDir")
getwd()

mydata <- read.csv("Attributes.csv", sep = ";")
library(dplyr)
soil_at <- mydata %>% select("X","Y","PH","CACO3","SAND","SILT", "CLAY" ,"OM","CEC")

install.packages("gstat")
library(gstat)
install.packages("sp")
library(sp)
install.packages("sf")
library(sf)
install.packages("moments")
library(moments)
install.packages("raster")
library(raster)

coordinates(soil_at)=~X+Y
v.cloud.pH<-variogram(soil_at$PH~ 1, data = soil_at, cloud=T)
head(v.cloud.pH)
plot(v.cloud.pH, main = "Variogram cloud - pH", xlab = "Separation distance (m)")

#Spherical (Shp) Model
# Intial parameter set by eye esitmation
m.sph.PH<-vgm(0.030,"Sph",4200,0.018)
# least square fit
m.sph.PH.f<-fit.variogram(v.pH, m.sph.PH)
m.sph.PH.f
plot(v.pH, pl=F, model=m.sph.PH.f,col="black", cex=1, lwd=0.5,lty=1,pch=20,
     main="pH Variogram - Spherical Model",xlab="Distance (m)",ylab="Semivariance")
#Ordinary Kriging#
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(gstat)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(car)
library(classInt)
library(RStoolbox)
library(spatstat)
library(dismo)
library(fields)
library(gridExtra)

mydata <- read.csv("Attributes.csv", sep = ";")
library(dplyr)
soil_at <- mydata %>% select("X","Y","PH","CACO3","SAND","SILT", "CLAY" ,"OM","CEC")
soil_at.coords <- soil_at %>% select("X","Y")
Clay.data <- soil_at$CLAY
```

I have stack here, and i do not know how to continue to Ordinary Kriging! Any solution or idea, please?

As an alternative, because i have stack with the grid i run this:

```
setwd("D:/R/WorkDir")
getwd()
install.packages(c("gstat","sp"))
library(gstat)
library(sp)
data <- read.csv("Attributes.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
head(data)

class(data$X)
class(data$Y)

data$X <- as.numeric(data$X)
data$Y <- as.numeric(data$Y)

#Inverse Distance Weighting IDW

install.packages("sf")
library(sf)
install.packages("raster")
library(raster)
install.packages("dismo")
library(dismo)
install.packages("tmap")
library(tmap)

f_spdf = sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = cbind(data$X,data$Y), data = data, proj4string = sp::CRS(projargs = "+init=epsg:2100"))

#Generation of an empirical variogram based on the data 
var= gstat::variogram(object = data$CLAY~1, locations = f_spdf)
plot(var)

##nugget ~ 60
##sill ~ 100
##Range ~ 8000

#Fit an estimated semivariogram to the data
fit_var = gstat::fit.variogram(object = var, model = gstat::vgm(psill = 100, nugget = 60, range = 8000, model = "Sph"))

#Plot and compare results
plot(var, model = fit_var)
#Generated unknown points to interpolate
samp = sp::spsample(x = f_spdf, n = 1000, type = "random")

#Kriging

krig = gstat::krige(formula = data$CLAY~1, locations = f_spdf, newdata = samp, model = fit_var)

head(krig@data)

install.packages("tmap")
library(tmap)

install.packages("terra")

tmap = tm_shape(shp = krig) + tm_dots(col = "var1.pred")
tmap
```

But it does not work, and i think thaat the samp is wrong as it does not create values in var1.pred Any idea?

Comment: What package are you using for kriging? Because you'll have to make sure the object specifying the grid is correct for your kriging functions. Edit the question and maybe show us the code you used for the variogram and some more information about your shapefile?

Comment: @Spacedman the shapefile has the perimeterof the area. I changed and updated with code